# find stock composition of a publicly traded fund

Tags: stocks, investing, yahoo-finance

I would like to find out which stocks a publicly traded fund is composed of?

Is this a publicly accessible information, or is it confidential?

For the sake of example, lets take the [EuroPac International Dividend Income Fund](http://www.europacificfunds.com/funds/international-dividend-income-fund)

Both on the fund's offical page, and on [Yahoo Finance](http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/EPDPX/holdings?p=EPDPX), I can only see the top 10 stock positions.

Is it possible to find out all the positions?

Comment: Try looking at the published annual report: http://europacificfunds.com/funds/international-dividend-income-fund/downloads/annual

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The big websites, Yahoo and the like, only give the 10 biggest positions of any fund.
Download the [annual report of the fund](http://europacificfunds.com/funds/international-dividend-income-fund/downloads/annual), **go to page 18**, you will find the positions on the 31st of December. 
However the actual positions could be different.

The same applies to all funds. **You need the annual report**.